# System hangs once in 2-3 days after installing DDR2 667Mhz RAM with a 533Mhz RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance

My Compaq Presario desktop with Windows7 professional installed becomes completely unresponsive once in 2-3 days, since I added an extra 2GB 667Mhz DDR2 ram to it. As told on the official hp site, my computer supports upto 4GB DDR2 ram. However the previously installed RAM was 533MHz & the new one is 667Mhz.

After hanging, nothing even the CTRL+ALT+DEL doesn't work. Just prior to hang, there is no slowing down of the computer, it just becomes *instantly* unresponsive.

Is that a RAM incompatibility issue?

---

My Computer model is : SG3745IL

Comment: What is your exact computer model?

Comment: @iglvzx: added model no to the question

Comment: If you remove the new RAM stick, does the issue still occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually machines are smart enough and act as the slowest speed of memory out of all the modules you have installed.

That being said, it is possible that either the speed detection has failed, or, the laptop just isn't that great.

My recommendation is that if you are 100% certain you installed the memory correctly and have isolated it to that, uninstall the module that was originally in there.

If you are no longer having the issue, it was an incompatibility between the new and old module, if however you are still having the issue, first run a [memory test tool](http://www.memtest.org), then if that is positive, great - if it is negative, I think it could be that the module just isn't compatible with your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a Memory Test? In Windows 7, you can click on the Start Orb, type `memory` and choose the Memory Test option that appears. Alternatively, you can download MemTest86